# MATLAB colormapping issue with value 0

Tags: matlab, color-mapping

I already searched the web and stack overflow for answers to this (seemingly simple) question, however could't find the answer:

I am in the progress of writing a cellular automaton in MATLAB. I am using an n*m matrix with values between 0 and 15, from which I make an image using a colormap with 5 grey values (between 0 and 1). See the following code snippet to clarify this:

```
WIDTH = 100;
HEIGHT = 100;

fields = randi(16,HEIGHT,WIDTH)-1;
% here the grey values 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1 are mapped to the values 1 to 16
cmRow = [1;0.75;0.75;0.5;0.75;0.5;0.5;0.25;0.75;0.5;0.5;0.25;0.5;0.25;0.25;0];
specialGray = [cmRow, cmRow, cmRow];
colormap(specialGray);
image(fields)
```

Well my problem is, that there is no 0th row in the colormap that MATLAB would use, if a value 0 occurs. As a result, there is always one color missing.
Just using values from 1 to 16 instead of from 0 to 15 is unfortunately not an option, as I heavily rely on these values later in the script.
Is there something obvious, I am missing? Do you have any ideas how to tackle this issue?

Thank you very much!
Best regards,
René

Comment: Does this `image(fields+1)` solve your issue?

Comment: Oh, it's the obvious, that i oversaw. It works! Thank you so much for helping me with this one! I should definitely take a break!

Answer (score 1):

The `image` function knows two type of color mapping: `direct'  (the default) and 'scaled'. If you use 'scaled', you can set the scale for the color with the`caxis` function. Thus, the following code should do the trick (but you can of course also transform the values as suggested by Oleg):

```
image(fields,'CDataMapping','scaled');
colormap(specialGray);
caxis([0 15]);
```